# Uso de Extends en Java

Tags: java, herencia

Si en un proyecto quiero llamar a un método con otro método dentro, ¿Es necesario el uso de `extends`? He realizado algún ejercicio con `extends`y `this` pero no entiendo bien la diferencia, en este caso que expongo, ¿Podría usar `extends` en lugar de lo que veis?

```
public class EjemploThis {
public static void main (String[] args){
    String name = "Rex";
    String type = "Chihuahua";
    int age = 10;
    int energy = 100;
    bark();}

static void bark(){
    System.out.println("Woff");  } 

void atack() {} //Método atacar     
void run(){} //Método correr

void defendHouse() { //Método defender la casa
    this.bark();
    this.atack();} }
```

Comment: bueno, al menos necesitarías 2 clases diferentes para que tenga algún sentido usar extend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si en un proyecto quiero llamar a un método con otro método dentro,
>   ¿Es necesario el uso de extends?

No.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        imprimir();

    }

    static void imprimir(){
        System.out.println("Hola soy imprimir y me llamaron desde main");
        imprimir1();
    }

    static void imprimir1(){
        System.out.println("Hola soy imprimir1 y me llamaron desde imprimir");
    }
```

http://ideone.com/c5JlP2

---

> ¿Es necesario el uso de extends?

El uso de `extends` esta relacionado estrechamente con la herencia, y el polimorfismo ("aunque suelen aplicar herencia sin polimorfismo pero entrar en eso seria un poco basado en opiniones cuando podrian usar composicion"), `extends` basicamente descrito de forma rapida para que te hagas una idea lo que hace es que hereda todo el contenido de una clase dentro de la clase a la que se le aplica extends ("bueno realmente todo no dependera de otros factores `private`, `protect` ect te dejo unos video que igual te ayudan a entender mejor").

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLy7u_sU-vEtNjogvcGox9EYWYkujavhgX

```
public class Animal {
    int patas;
}

public class Perro extends Animal {

}
```

ahora al hacer el extends `Perro` cuenta con la variable `patas`, y si con los metodos de Animal si los tuviera, eso es a rasgos simples.

---

Ahora sobre `this` te pondre un ejemplo espero te aclare

```
public class Animal {

String nombre;

    public void ejemplo(String nombre){  //puedes ver que el 
                                         //identificador de la 
                                         //variable es el mismo 
                                         //que el que tienes a nivel 
                                         //de class los dos son nombre

         this.nombre = nombre;           //en este caso usamos
                                         //this.nombre para referirnos
                                         //a la variable que esta fuera
                                         //del metodo y nombre se a la
                                         //refiere a la que se le pasa al
                                         //al metodo


    }

}
```

Existen muchos usos para la palabra `this`, tambien se puede usar para la llamada a otro constructor de la clase ver ejemplo siguiente sacado de [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

*Seria algo como esta ilustracion mas o menos igual entiende mejor*

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() { <-- si usted hiciera Rectangle rec = new Rectagle();
        this(0, 0, 1, 1); -- call -------------------------------
------->                                                         |  
|   }                                                            |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |  
|   public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) { <-----
|       |   this.x = x;                  
|       |   this.y = y;
|       |   this.width = width;
|       |   this.height = height;
|   }   |
 --------      
}
```

> Dentro de un método de instancia o de un constructor, `this` es una
>   referencia al objeto actual - el objeto cuyo método o constructor que
>   se está llamando. Puede referirse a cualquier miembro del objeto
>   actual desde el interior de un método de instancia o un constructor
>   mediante el uso de `this`.

Comment: los videos son largos y algo antiguos pero si los ves con paciencia creo que entenderas muchas cosas, puedes verlos varias veces no tienes porque entenderlo todo a la primera, espero te ayude Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha aclarado bastante

Answer (score 0):

La palabra reservada `this` hace referencia al mismo objeto

```
Class A{protected int a; public int getA(){return this.a;}}
```

Para este caso `this` se usa para referenciar características del objeto, métodos y atributos

```
Class B extends A{ int b; public int getB(){return this.b;}  public int getC(){return super.a +this.b ;}}
```

La palabra reservada `super` hace referencia a su padre

Para conocer más del tema http://www.aprenderaprogramar.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=653:ejemplo-de-herencia-en-java-uso-de-palabras-clave-extends-y-super-constructores-con-herencia-cu00686b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188