# Visualizar dos instancias de array

Tags: java, array

Buenos días, estoy enfrascado en diseñar dos tableros para un juego (Hundir la Flota), a pequeños pasos, tengo una clase `MyDesk` donde he creado dos instancias de tablero, sin embargo, al llamar a ambas desde una clase main (`MyDesk barco = new MyDesk()` `EnemyDesk enemigo = new EnemyDesk()`), solo se visualiza la primera, ¿se debe a que ambas están incluídas en la misma clase?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MyDesk {

    int [][] barcosvivos;

    public MyDesk(){
        this.barcosvivos = new int[5][5];
        barcosvivos [1][0] = 1; barcosvivos [2][0] = 1; barcosvivos[3][0]=1;
        barcosvivos [1][2]= 1; barcosvivos [1][3]= 1; barcosvivos [1][4]= 1;
        for (int []interno: this.barcosvivos){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno));}    
    }

    public MyDesk (int [][] EnemyDesk){
        EnemyDesk = new int [5][5];
        EnemyDesk [0][2] = 3; EnemyDesk [0][3] = 3; EnemyDesk [0][4] = 3;
        EnemyDesk [2][0] = 3; EnemyDesk [2][1] = 3; EnemyDesk [2][2] = 3;
        for (int []interno2: EnemyDesk){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno2));}
    }
}
```

El código que uso en `Main` es:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        MyDesk barco = new MyDesk();
        MyDesk prueba = new MyDesk();
    } 
}
```

Comment: La respuesta es `Sí y No`.

Asumo que en el `void Main() {}` estas declarando dos instancias de `MyDesk`  donde usas el mismo constructor, así que por defecto ambas instancias deben de tener las mismas posiciones.

Tambien _(no soy muy de java)_, pero dentro del codigo del segundo constructor, creo que la variable no es de salida/referencia (`int[][] EnemyDesk`).

Comment: ¿Tienes el código que utilizas en el `main`?

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema de conceptos. No deberías tener 2 clases que sean un `Desk`, solo una y dos instancias que realizan lo que necesita esa clase.

Comment: Entonces creo que no lo entiendo bien, tanto `public MyDesk ()` como `public MyDesk (int [][] EnemyDesk)` no serían ambas dos instancias de `class MyDesk` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desconozco que tienes en la clase `EnemyDesk` pero estás sobrecargando  de manera incorrecta el constructor de la clase MyDesk.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class MyDesk {

    int [][] barcosvivos;
    int [][] barcosenemigos;

    public MyDesk(){
        barcosvivos = new int[5][5];
        barcosvivos [1][0] = 1; barcosvivos [2][0] = 1; barcosvivos[3][0]=1;
        barcosvivos [1][2]= 1; barcosvivos [1][3]= 1; barcosvivos [1][4]= 1;

        barcosenemigos = new int [5][5];
        barcosenemigos[0][2] = 3; barcosenemigos[0][3] = 3; barcosenemigos[0][4] = 3;
        barcosenemigos[2][0] = 3; barcosenemigos[2][1] = 3; barcosenemigos[2][2] = 3;
    }

    public void showAllyDesk () {
        for (int []interno: this.barcosvivos){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno));}    
    }

    public void showEnemyDesk () {
        for (int []interno2: this.barcosenemigos){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno2));}
   }
}
```

Y luego en tu main

```
MyDesk tablero = new MyDesk();
tablero.showAllyDesk();
tablero.showEnemyDesk();
```

Por supuesto, si quieres que los tableros varien la posición de los barcos cada vez que lo ejecutas, tendrás que sacarlo del constructor, o armar algo que los genere de manera azarosa, realmente no sé dónde apunta tu pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Asumo que en su main tiene algo asi:

```
MyDesk barco = new MyDesk();
EnemyDesk enemigo = new EnemyDesk();
```

si lo anterior compila, usted tiene una clase del tipo EnemyDesk, pero en esta parte `public MyDesk (int [][] EnemyDesk){` usa la misma palabra no se si es que lo que queria es poder pasar una instacia de EnemyDesk o que simplemente paso de la convencion, creo y me inclino que es la segunda, pues dentro del constructor usted trata a EnemyDesk como un array de tipos integrados de alguna marera, entre otras cosa pero creo que a simple vista es confuso por el simple echo de ver `int [][] EnemyDesk` y anteriormente poner `EnemyDesk enemigo = new EnemyDesk();`.

Ahora si entiendo bien su pregunta quizas lo que busque se a algo como esto:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        MyDesk barco = new MyDesk();
        //EnemyDesk enemigo = new EnemyDesk();// es confusa esta parte

        int [][] enemyDesk = null;
        MyDesk barco1 = new MyDesk(enemyDesk);
}
```

---

```
class MyDesk {
int [][] barcosvivos;
    public MyDesk(){
        this.barcosvivos = new int[5][5];
        barcosvivos [1][0] = 1; barcosvivos [2][0] = 1; barcosvivos[3][0]=1;
        barcosvivos [1][2]= 1; barcosvivos [1][3]= 1; barcosvivos [1][4]= 1;
        for (int []interno: this.barcosvivos){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno));}    
    }
    public MyDesk (int [][] enemyDesk){ 
        enemyDesk = new int [5][5];
        enemyDesk [0][2] = 3; enemyDesk [0][3] = 3; enemyDesk [0][4] = 3;
        enemyDesk [2][0] = 3; enemyDesk [2][1] = 3; enemyDesk [2][2] = 3;
        for (int []interno2: enemyDesk){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno2));}
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Test ideone](https://ideone.com/ybUA6G)</kbd>

P.D: para entender lo que comente sobre la convencion puede mirar esto: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_Nombres_(Programaci%C3%B3n)#Java

---

Yo no se si este es el comportamiento que esperaba cuando lo diseño, segun esta usted tiene que llamar a a los dos constructores para que se muestren las dos salidas por ejemplo:

- `MyDesk barco = new MyDesk(); --> llama a -> public MyDesk(){`
- `MyDesk barco1 = new MyDesk(enemyDesk); --> llama a -> public MyDesk
     (int [][] enemyDesk){`

si quiere que se llamen a los dos independientemente del constructor que se llame inicialmente puede hacer uso de `this` si no sabe como trabajar con ellas o como funcionan puede mirar estas respuestas de alguna manera se explica el como aplicarlo:

[Uso de Extends en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6759/uso-de-extends-en-java/6778#6778)

---

**Update por comentario:**

> Hola Angel, he probado con tu corrección y efectivamente logro que
>   aparezcan dos tableros, pero ambos son el mismo,

no entiendo lo que dice con ambos son el mismo:

**barco:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**barco1:**

```
[0, 0, 3, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

> es decir, en ambos casos se visualiza el tablero MyDesk() en lugar de
>   que en el segundo aparezca con las variaciones de MyDesk (int [][]
>   enemyDesk)

*si usted quiere que se visualice lo que se le pase tiene que hacer algunos cambios:*

Sample main:

```
    int [][] EnemyDesk = null;
    EnemyDesk = new int [5][5];

    EnemyDesk [0][2] = 1; 
    EnemyDesk [0][3] = 1; 
    EnemyDesk [0][4] = 1;
    EnemyDesk [2][0] = 3; 
    EnemyDesk [2][1] = 3; 
    EnemyDesk [2][2] = 3;

    MyDesk barco1 = new MyDesk(EnemyDesk); //<- le pasas EnemyDesk
```

Class MyDesk, cambiar esta parte:

```
 public MyDesk (int [][] EnemyDesk){

    for (int []interno2: EnemyDesk){System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interno2));}
}
```

Notas: le recomiendo que analice la respueta de @MarceloZárate pues si esta es funcional para lo que busca tiene mejor diseño en mi opinion que la que usted esta mostrando en su pregunta (pero yo no se si eso es apto para lo que busca) de ser asi podria añadir algo como lo siguiente a la respueta mencionada:

```
public MyDesk(int [][] EnemyDesk){

    barcosvivos = new int[5][5];
    barcosvivos [1][0] = 1; barcosvivos [2][0] = 1; barcosvivos[3][0]=1;
    barcosvivos [1][2]= 1; barcosvivos [1][3]= 1; barcosvivos [1][4]= 1;

    barcosenemigos = EnemyDesk;  
}
```

Comment: Hola Angel, he probado con tu corrección y efectivamente logro que aparezcan dos tableros, pero ambos son el mismo, es decir, en ambos casos se visualiza el tablero `MyDesk()` en lugar de que en el segundo aparezca con las variaciones de `MyDesk (int [][] enemyDesk)`  ¿tendría que realizar las variaciones (posiciones distintas de los barcos) en el propio main?