# ¿Cómo puedo dar un ejemplo del uso de la palabra reservada this?

Tags: java

me dejaron dar un ejemplo sobre la palabra reservada this, pero no se como funciona esta clase. Podrían explicarme que debo hacer por favor.

Comment: `this` en bajo nivel es un puntero a la instancia de la clase actual a la cual haces referencia, por eso siempre en la mayoría de los lenguajes, cuando proceden a usar  `this` lo hacen de esta forma `this->`, (con el operador de miembro el cual también es usado cuando haces referencia a una instancia a través de un puntero), pero creo que deberías usar otro tipo de ejemplificación...

Comment: la pregunta es distinta pero pienso en las respuesta puede ver algunos ejemplos del uso de `this` y su significado -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6759/uso-de-extends-en-java/ Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el ejemplo más "fácil" sería algo como el siguiente.
tenemos las variables de la clase `CAlgo` así:

```
private int edad;
```

ahora implementamos el método `setEdad()`

```
public void setEdad(int edad){}
```

el "problema" viene aquí: `edad = edad;` ¿cómo sabe java qué jalar? ¿la variable de la clase o la variable del método? Bueno, la respuesta es: *no puede saberlo por sí solo.*

debes especificar la variable (también con métodos) que debe usar.

Sabiendo esto, ahora quedaría de:

```
public void setEdad(int edad){
edad = edad;
}
```

a quedar:

```
public void setEdad(int edad){
this.edad = edad;
}
```

Ahora la teoría:

`this` llama a los métodos de la clase, atributos o variables de una clase específica.

como:

```
 public void setEdad(int edad){
this.edad = edad;
}

public void setEdadPorDefault(){
this.setEdad(10);//10 años por omisión (default)
}
```

también retorna `this` con un:

```
public X Metodo(X var){
//operaciones
return this;
}
```

> PD: estas preguntas no son aceptadas, te las van a cerrar o bajar
>   puntos, revisa las normas y reglas de este sitio.

Comment: `this` no llama a ningún método, solo hace referencia a la instancia actual, cuando todo es compilado las clases no existen mas, que los lenguajes estén hechos con otra lógica es otra cosa...

Answer (score 4):

La pregunta puede ser interesante, si la mejoras un poco.

Para explicar la palabra reservada `this`voy a recurrir a la [Documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), ya que la misma está en inglés será la ocasión para tenerla traducida al castellano.

## Usando la palabra reservada this

Dentro de un método de instancia o un constructor, se trata de una referencia al objeto actual: el objeto cuyo método o constructor está siendo llamado. Puede hacer referencia a cualquier miembro del objeto actual desde un método de instancia o un constructor utilizando `this`.

### Usando this con un campo

La razón más común para utilizar la palabra reservada `this` es porque un campo está sombreado por un parámetro de método o constructor.

Por ejemplo, la clase `Point` escrita de esta manera:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Podría haberse escrito también así:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Cada argumento al constructor sombrea uno de los campos del objeto - dentro del constructor **x** es una copia local del primer argumento del constructor. Para referirse al campo **x** de la clase `Point`, el constructor debe usar **`this.x`**.

#### Ejemplo gráfico

Los colores de cada línea indican a qué ámbito pertenece el campo referenciado por `this`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Usando this con un constructor

Desde dentro de un constructor, también puede usar la palabra clave `this` para llamar a otro constructor en la misma clase. Hacerlo se denomina invocación explícita del constructor. Aquí hay otra clase `Rectangle`, con una implementación diferente a la de la sección [Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    ...
    }
```

Esta clase contiene un conjunto de constructores. Cada constructor inicializa algunas o todas las variables miembro de la clase `Rectangle`. Los constructores proporcionan un valor predeterminado para cualquier variable de miembro cuyo valor inicial no es proporcionado por un argumento. Por ejemplo, el constructor sin argumentos crea un `Rectangle` 1x1 en coordenadas 0,0. El constructor de dos argumentos llama al constructor de cuatro argumentos, pasando por el ancho y la altura, pero siempre usando las coordenadas 0,0. Como antes, el compilador determina qué constructor debe llamar, en función del número y el tipo de argumentos.

Si está presente, la invocación de otro constructor debe ser la primera línea en el constructor.

#### Ejemplo gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]