# Para que sirve this.dispose?

Tags: java

Vi esta parte de un codigo en internet:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo encontre buscando algo que necesitaba pero no me cambia en nada la funcionalidad del resto del codigo, queria saber para que se utilizaba.

Comment: La funcion dispose sirve para lo que viene siendo la limpieza. dispose() se encarga de eliminar un objeto y asi liberar recursos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.exit();` hace que la VM Java termine completamente.

`JFrame.dispose();`hace que la ventana JFrame sea destruida y limpiada por el sistema operativo. De acuerdo con la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29), esto puede hacer que la máquina virtual de Java termine si no hay ninguna otra ventana disponible, pero esto realmente debería ser visto como un efecto secundario en lugar de la norma.

El que elijas realmente depende de tu situación. Si deseas terminar todo en la máquina virtual de Java actual, debes utilizar `System.exit()`y todo se limpia. Si sólo deseas destruir la ventana actual, con el efecto secundario que va a cerrar la VM Java si ésta es la única ventana, a continuación, utilice `JFrame.dispose()`.

Answer (score 6):

### `this`

Es una palabra reservada de Java para hacer referencia al **objeto actual**. Al usarse junto con `dispose()` se referirá entonces a la **ventana actual**, por lo que se explica en la descripción de `dispose()`.

Para más detalles sobre `this`, puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66559/29967).

---

### `dispose`

[`dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose--)  es un método de la clase [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) el cual, según la documentación:

> Libera todos los recursos nativos de pantalla utilizados por esta
>   ventana, sus subcomponentes y todos sus hijos. Es decir, los recursos
>   para estos componentes se destruirán, cualquier memoria que consuman
>   será devuelta al sistema operativo y se marcarán como no visible.
>
> La ventana y sus subcomponentes se pueden volver a mostrar de nuevo
>   reconstruyendo los recursos nativos con una llamada posterior a [`pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--)
>   o [`show`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#show--) (éste último declarado obsoleto al ser reemplazado por [`setVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible-boolean-). Los estados de la Ventana recreada y sus
>   subcomponentes serán idénticos a los estados de estos objetos en el
>   punto en que se dispuso la Ventana (sin contar las modificaciones
>   adicionales entre esas acciones).
>
> Nota: Cuando se elimine la última ventana visualizable dentro de la
>   máquina virtual Java (VM), la VM puede finalizar. Consulte [Temas de
>   subprocesos AWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html#Autoshutdown) para obtener más información.

Answer (score 2):

Con esa instrucción cierras la ventana actual y liberas los recursos que esa ventana haya estado ocupando.