# ¿Cual es el uso de la palabra reservada "this"? Java

Tags: java

Me ha surgido una duda con el uso de la palabra "this" en java.

Tengo entendido que el uso de this es para decirle que nos estamos refiriendo a la variable de clase, por ejemplo:

```
private int a;

public Constructor(int a){
  this.a = a;
}
```

Pero la he visto en otros casos al decirle que el oyente es la misma, por ejemplo:

```
addActionListener(this);
```

> **¿Pero cómo es que se comunica o que proceso hace la palabra this?**

*Si me pudiera explicar en otras palabras que uso o que funcionalidad es la que ejerce se los agradeceria.*

Comment: Ese **this** hace referencia a un objeto de la clase actual. Es decir si llamas al metodo addActionListener desde una clase llamada "User", este toma de referencia un objeto de la misma.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo dar un ejemplo del uso de la palabra reservada this?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66552/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-dar-un-ejemplo-del-uso-de-la-palabra-reservada-this). En [una de las respuestas dadas allí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/66559/29967) se ha traducido lo que dice la documentación de Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de la palabra *this* se utiliza para hacer referencia al objeto "actual". Si estás diseñando una clase, this hace referencia a la propia clase.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que, en las clases anidadas (del tipo que sean), usar this hace referencia a la clase anidada. En caso de querer hacer referencia a la clase envolvente tienes que usar el nombre de la clase envonvelte.this:

```
class ClaseEnvolvente{
 int entero=0; //Entero de la clase envolvente
 class Interna{
  int entero=0; //Entero de la clase anidada
  public ClaseInterna(int entero){

   /*this hace referencia la clase propia, es decir, ClaseInterna, por lo que
   estaremos haciendo referencia al entero de la clase anidada*/
   this.entero=entero; 

   /*Para hacer referencia al propio objeto de la clase envolvente
   tienes que utilizar el nombre de la clase envolvente seguido de this:*/
   ClaseEnvolvente.this.entero=entero;
   }
  }
 }
```

Es válido para cualquier uso en el que necesites hacer referencia explícita al objeto, como por ejemplo un método que devuelve un duplicado de si mismo. Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
public class ConstructorDuplicados {
    private int entero;

    //Constructor inicial
    public ConstructorDuplicados(int entero) {
        this.entero=entero;
    }

    //Constructor para duplicar un objeto del mismo tipo que la clase
    private ConstructorDuplicados(ConstructorDuplicados in) {
        this.entero=in.entero;
    }

    //Método de la clase que duplica al propio objeto desde el que se invoca
    public ConstructorDuplicados getCopia() {
        //Este método llama al constructor de duplicados pasandose como argumento "a sí mismo" (this) 
        return new ConstructorDuplicados(this);
    }
}
```

Siempre que tengas cualquier duda sobre la implementación de algo, echa un vistazo a los tutoriales de Java de Oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.