# ¿Que significa "this" en este fragmento de codigo?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo como tarea hacer este codigo pero con arreglo normales[], mi problema es que necesito saber que signica this en el metodo inscribir, o sea que significa 
que this esté como un atributo en el objeto inscripcion.

Se me dificulta algo POO y no comprendo porque el this esta situado allí, el codigo funciona bien es de mi profesor pero no comprendo que hace él en el metodo incribir y generar grupos

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    package mundo;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Materia
{  
  protected Grupo [] grupos;  
  protected ArrayList<Inscripcion> inscripciones;  
  protected String nombre;  
  protected int maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo;  

public Materia(String nombre, int maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo)
{
  setNombre(nombre);
  setMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo(maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo);
  this.inscripciones = new ArrayList<Inscripcion>();
  this.grupos = new Grupo[0];
}//fin constructor

public boolean inscribir(Alumno alumno)
{
  boolean inscribio = false;
  Inscripcion inscripcion = new Inscripcion(alumno, this);
  if(!alumno.tienePromedioCondicional() && 
      !this.inscripciones.contains(inscripcion)){
   this.inscripciones.add(inscripcion);
   inscribio = true;
  }
  return inscribio;
}//fin inscribir

public boolean generarGrupos()
{
  int totalGrupos = this.inscripciones.size()  /  this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo;
  totalGrupos  += this.inscripciones.size()  %  this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo !=0 ? 1: 0;
  int k=0;
  this.grupos = new Grupo[totalGrupos];

  for(int i=0; i<totalGrupos; i++)
  {
    this.grupos[i] = new Grupo(this);
  }//fin for i

  for(int i=0; i<this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<totalGrupos-(this.inscripciones.size()  %  this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo !=0 ? 1: 0); j++)
    {
      this.grupos[j].agregarAlumno(this.inscripciones.get(k++).getAlumno());
    }//fin for j
  }//fin for i

  for(int i=k;i<this.inscripciones.size();i++)
    this.grupos[totalGrupos-1].agregarAlumno(this.inscripciones.get(i).getAlumno());

  return totalGrupos > 0;

}//fin generarGrupos

/**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad nombre*/
public String getNombre(){
    return this.nombre;
}//end method getNombre

/**Metodo de modificación a la propiedad nombre*/
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}//end method setNombre

/**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo*/
public int getMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo(){
    return this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo;
}//end method getMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo

/**Metodo de modificación a la propiedad maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo*/
public void setMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo(int maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo){
    this.maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo = maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo;
}//end method setMaximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo

/**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad Grupos*/
public Grupo[] getGrupos(){
    return this.grupos;
}//end method getGrupos

/**Metodo de acceso a la propiedad inscripciones*/
public java.util.ArrayList<Inscripcion> getInscripciones(){
    return this.inscripciones;
}//end method getInscripciones

/***/
public Grupo getGrupo(int numero)
{
  return this.grupos[numero];
}//fin getGrupo

/**Compara el nombre de this con un String u otro Materia*/
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
  if(other instanceof String) return this.nombre.equals(other);
  if(other instanceof Materia) return this.nombre.equals(((Materia)other).getNombre());
  return false;
}//fin equals
```

}//fin class Materia

Y tambien necesito algo de ayuda en el metodo generar grupos ya que lo leo y no lo comprendo :/, solo necesito una explicacion en lenguaje natural de este metodo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo dar un ejemplo del uso de la palabra reservada this?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66552/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-dar-un-ejemplo-del-uso-de-la-palabra-reservada-this)

Answer (score 2):

Si tuvieses el siguiente código:

```
public class Materia
{  
  protected Grupo [] grupos;  
  protected ArrayList<Inscripcion> inscripciones;  
  protected String nombre;  
  protected int maximoDeAlumnosPorGrupo;  

//El resto del código

public boolean inscribir(Alumno alumno)
{
  boolean inscribio = false;
  Inscripcion inscripciones = new Inscripcion(alumno, this); //le he cambiado el nombre a la variable
  if(!alumno.tienePromedioCondicional() && 
      !this.inscripciones.contains(inscripciones)){
   this.inscripciones.add(inscripciones);
   inscribio = true;
  }
  return inscribio;
}//fin inscribir
```

En este ejemplo tienes 2 variables con el nombre "inscripciones": El de tipo ArrayList y el de tipo Incripcion.

¿Cómo puedes entonces hacer `inscripciones.add(inscripciones);`? Esto sería ambiguo. Por tanto se usa this : `this.inscripciones.add(inscripciones);` This hace referencia al propio objeto, en este caso el objeto Materia. Así estás indicando que quieres asignarle el incripciones (de tipo Inscripción) al inscripciones de tipo ArrayList y miembro de la clase Materia. Así se ha resuelto la ambiguedad.

Otro ejemplo más sencillo es el setter que tienes para "nombre":

```
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Cuando haces `this.nombre = nombre;` estás indicando que al miembro nombre de Materia le asignas nombre (el argumento del setter). Si no usas this no podrías distinguir a qué nombre te refieres.

Comment: En este caso si no se usa `this` se estará haciendo referencia al la variable declarada dentro del método. Por eso es necesario el `this` en caso de que quieras referirte al atributo de la clase. A esto se le conoce como Shadow Variable.

Answer (score 1):

This se refiere a la clase en este caso Materia , me imagino que inscripciones es la cantidad de inscripciones que puede tener una materia haciendo referencia a la misma clase en la que estás , por eso escribe this.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas `this` estás haciendo referencia a el objeto en el que estas trabajando, en el caso de tu código sería una instancia de la clase Materia, como bien te dijeron.
Para que te des una idea, si crearas otro objeto llamado 'ejemplo', dentro de un determinado método de la clase que también posea un método llamado `generarGrupos()`, cuando escribas `this.generarGrupos()` (o `generarGrupos()`, el `this` está implicito) llamarás al método `generarGrupos()` de la instancia de la clase Materia, en cambio si escribes `ejemplo.generarGrupos()`, estarás llamando al método `generarGrupos()` pero del objeto 'ejemplo'.

Comment: Nop. La palabra reservada `this` hace referencia al objeto en si, o sea a la instancia. Si llamas a `generarGrupos()` es lo mismo que si lo haces así `this.generarGrupos()`. Para que in método sea de la clase y no de la instancia tiene que incluir el modificar `static`.